# Making qgis2web web map display description rather than value of field with valuemap widget

Tags: qgis, qgis2web, widget

I am making a web map with qgis2web which I want the pop-up to display the description rather than the value from a field which I have a value map widget on. Is this possible, or should I just make another field for my description?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid this isn't supported by qgis2web. Making another field (even a virtual one) with the expanded values is the way to go in this instance.